# BOOLEAN Search MySQL not working for certain words

Tags: mysql, search, boolean

I am having a problem with boolean searching, firstly I thought it was something wrong with my database/table but then i tried creating following sample table with 1 column and sample values and result is same, it successfully runs for some words and fails for others, any ideas?

Queries that run successfully:

```
SELECT * FROM `temp` WHERE (match (txt) against ('develo*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)>0 ) 
SELECT * FROM `temp` WHERE (match (txt) against ('devel*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)>0 ) 
SELECT * FROM `temp` WHERE (match (txt) against ('senio*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)>0 )
```

But when I try doing similar search against words 'second' or 'third', it fails

```
SELECT * FROM `temp` WHERE (match (txt) against ('secon*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)>0 ) 
SELECT * FROM `temp` WHERE (match (txt) against ('third*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)>0 )
```

--- Following is the sample table and values -----

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp` (
  `txt` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `temp`
--

INSERT INTO `temp` (`txt`) VALUES
('developer'),
('Developer'),
('Developer senior'),
('senior developer'),
('second job'),
('job second'),
('third'),
('third job'),
('job third');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [stopwords list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-stopwords.html) is applied in BOOLEAN MODE match, words `second` and `third` are just ignored by the engine.

You can override the default stopwords list with your own, as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-search.html):

> To override the default stopword list, set the `ft_stopword_file` system
>   variable. [...] The variable value should be the path name of the file
>   containing the stopword list, or the empty string to disable stopword
>   filtering. The server looks for the file in the data directory unless
>   an absolute path name is given to specify a different directory. After
>   changing the value of this variable or the contents of the stopword
>   file, restart the server and rebuild your `FULLTEXT` indexes.

Comment: To follow-up: _Common words such as “some” or “then” are stopwords and do not match if present in the search string._

Comment: @BradChristie I gave the link to that list, so decided against quoting them here. ) But you're right, of course; stopwords list is the list of words regarded as 'too common' for trying to match them.

Comment: Thanks, this surely helps however do you happen to know what might be causing this behaviour.. if there is a term or word 'td' in my data and if I search for it using quotes like search: "td"   data: ' this is sample td data' .. it doesn't bring the result up